# Better Way to Declare List of TextViews?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a list of Clickable TextViews that are relatively doing the same thing. You click on it and it goes to that activity. Settings goes to the settings activity. About to the about and so forth. Is there an easier way to declare and set up these clickable TextViews besides this repetitious code?

```
 TextView create,
                         edit,
                         settings,
                         about;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

                create = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create);
                        create.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                edit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
                        edit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                settings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings);
                        settings.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                about = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.about);
                        about.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

                create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                        }      
                });

                edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v){

                        }
                });

                settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v){

                        }
                });

                about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v){

                        }
                });
```

Comment: Why not use the ListView control that was designed specifically for this purpose?

Comment: Not sure, this is my first app so I'm just kind of working with what I know. Will look into that though.

Comment: Gotcha. I definitely think you should go the ListView route though, most likely you will end up reusing it in the future and it's best to get accustomed to it now. It's very simple. Check it out here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: and here's another good tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a small set of items you can take following approach:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ArrayAdapter<Item> mAdapter;

    private static enum Item {Create,Edit,Settings,About}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //-- can set up from external layout also--
        ListView list = new ListView(this);
        setContentView(list);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Item.values());
        list.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        switch (mAdapter.getItem(i)){
            case Create:
                //--do stuff--
                break;
            case Edit:
                //--do stuff--
                break;
            case Settings:
                //--do stuff--
                break;
            case About:
                //--do stuff--
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the **View.OnClickListener** .

```
   public class YOURACTIVITY extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

And in the onCreate()-

```
   yourTextview.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and then

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Based on the view , set the action


}
```